# Firefox Addon browser.downloads.download call seems to fail whenever there's a period in the filename

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I'm trying to fix a 3rd party firefox addon. It's a button that saves the current page as a shortcut file in your downloads directory. It's worked for months, but just started failing a few weeks ago. The issue is with [these lines](https://gitlab.com/claderoki/QuickCut/-/blob/master/background.js#L52-67), reproduced here:

```
let filename = "";

if (settings.savePath) {
    filename += settings.savePath + "/";
}

filename += `${title}.${extension}`;

let file = new File([contents], filename);
let objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);

let downloadSettings = {
    url: objectUrl,
    filename: filename,
    incognito: tab.incognito
}

if (settings.saveAs !== null) {
    downloadSettings.saveAs = settings.saveAs;
}

browser.downloads.download(downloadSettings).then(null, (error) => console.log(error));
```

When the final line executes, `downloadSettings.filename` will have been set to something like `"dog.url"`, and the file will be saved with that name.

It used to work, but now when that final line is executed it throws an error:

> Error: filename must not contain illegal characters

In doing some debugging, it seems that I can save a file if it ends in `_url` but not `.url`, so it doesn't like the `.`.

This doesn't seem to match the [MDN documentation for this function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/downloads/download):

> filename (Optional): A string representing a file path relative to the default downloads directory — this provides the location where you want the file to be saved, and what filename you want to use. Absolute paths, empty paths, path components that start and/or end with a dot (.), and paths containing back-references (../) will cause an error. If omitted, this value will default to the filename already given to the download file, and a location immediately inside the downloads directory.

I'm on Firefox Developer 112.0b9 on Windows 10. I've looked for new relevant firefox bug tickets but haven't found any.

Comment: Also, for some reason I can only install 1 addon from a file at a time. When I try to add a second, the first goes away...

Comment: Can't confirm this behavior. Works fine with Firefox 111.0.1 on Windows. Have you checked your antivirus software? Maybe this is blocking it. - `.url` files are special like `.lnk` files and the extension is never shown on windows explorer, even if the setting to show all file extension is enabled.

Comment: I'm on Firefox Developer 112.0b9. Hm, it does seem to work with `.txt`, though I'm not sure how my antivirus could cause it to give that error. Maybe they updated firefox to disallow `.url` files.

Comment: I can confirm the behavior with 112 and it seems that there where changes made that sanitize the [filename](https://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-beta/rev/92e31c77313890eaa09939ab5a367cb1e4f3067b) which was added with 112, overall this may be related to a [security vulnerability](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2023-09/#CVE-2023-28163) which is tracked in [ticket 1817768](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1817768)

Comment: [This commit looks](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/diff/1cc5883b4347439b7cd871902bcda12531fca42f/uriloader/exthandler/nsExternalHelperAppService.cpp#3690) like it touches code that blocks `.url` extensions, but I don't have access to the bug.

Comment: Yes, it's related to the sanitizer functions which don't allow `.url` and other sensitive extension on windows. You should [create a new bug ticket](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/file-bug-report-or-feature-request-mozilla) and refer to 1815062 and 1817768 with the error you get on the extension when trying to save a file as `.url`.

Comment: Thank you. [I have done so](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1827115)